# Possible Bug in Nested Mixins in Media Queries using LESS

Tags: css, less

### **EDIT: RESOLVED**

I am working on a way to easily write LESS code that takes parameters but still works with media queries. This is turning out to be rather convoluted, but I have gotten it working – on all sizes except one. The medium and large sizes work, but small is for some reason not printing the parameter, leaving me with css like `font-size: ;`.

Here I define my media sizes:

```
@m-small = ~"screen and (max-width: 799px)";
@m-medium = ~"screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1299px)";
@m-large = ~"screen and (min-width: 1300px)";
```

Then, the main function I call, where `@attr` is the CSS property (e.g. `font-size`) and `@parameter` is the variable (e.g. `fs-medium`). To use this, I can write `.media('font-size', 'fs-medium')`, which is significantly less verbose than defining every media query.

**Edit:** There was a bug here, hence the problem; I have fixed it.

```
.media(@attr, @parameter) {
  @media @m-small {
    .small(@attr, @parameter); 
  }

  @media @m-medium {
    .medium(@attr, @parameter);
  }

  @media @m-large {
    .large(@attr, @parameter);
  }
}
```

These functions store the default values for parameters at various sizes, allowing me to consolidate where I define my variables, grouped by media query:

```
.small(@attr, @parameter) {
  @fs-small   : 1.4rem;
  @fs-medium  : 2.0rem;
  @fs-large   : 3.4rem;

  @logo-width : 10rem;

  .guards();
}

.medium(@attr, @parameter) {
  @fs-small   : 1.4rem;
  @fs-medium  : 2.4rem;
  @fs-large   : 3.8rem;

  @logo-width : 12rem;

  .guards();
}

.large(@attr, @parameter) {
  @fs-small   : 1.4rem;
  @fs-medium  : 1.8rem;
  @fs-large   : 5rem;

  @logo-width : auto;
  .guards();
}
```

In the above code, I call `.guards()` to render the content. This checks through my list of guards for one with a matching attribute, because LESS does not allow variables to be used in CSS property names. In these guards, I dynamically call the parameter, so that if I passed `fs-medium`, it will render `@fs-medium`'s value.

```
.guards() when (@attr = 'font-size') {
  font-size: @@parameter;
}
.guards() when (@attr = 'width') {
  width: @@parameter;
}
```

Now, as I said, this works fine for the medium and large sizes, so I feel like there is either a typo in my code (I've checked) or a bug in LESS. One piece of code that uses this is as follows:

```
nav {
    .media('font-size', 'fs-medium');
}
```

Which renders the following content:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 799px){
    nav{ font-size:; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1299px){
    nav{ font-size:2.4rem; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px){
    nav{ font-size:1.8rem; }
}
```

Why is the small font-size missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that I do indeed have a typo in my question, where I typed 'paremeter' under the `.small` mixin. I have edited it in the original post, but I am leaving it here for others trying to use media queries in LESS in a generalized way.

**Verdict:** typo.